# Overriding highlighting style for one syntax

Tags: syntax-highlighting, search, colorscheme, quickfix

My colour scheme (morning) doesn't play nice with the quickfix window: I cannot read the selected item's location, because the foreground and background colours are the same. Because of this I want to redefine some highlighting styles, e.g. for `Search` and `LineNr`. However, I only want to do this in the quickfix window.

When I edit `~/.vim/syntax/qf.vim` with my changes, this affects also highlighting in other syntaxes. How can I change highlighting styles for one syntax only? I'm using, for example:

```
hi Search ctermbg=white
```

Comment: May not help but I had some specific colors I wanted in help and text  files so I defined my own in help.vim `syn match myhelpComment " awk \| gawk \| sed "`
and put the color definition  in syncolor.vim.`SynColor myhelpComment gui=bold guifg=#000000 guibg=Azure`. Probably not the most elegant but it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the solution you suggest isn't possible. Vim's highlighting and colorscheme commands are global: any colours you set are set *everywhere*.

The best you could do is to change the colours everywhere when the quickfix window opens and then change them back when it closes, (or perhaps change them when entering the buffer and change them back when you leave it), but there is no way of having different highlighting applying in different windows simultaneously.

However, this shouldn't prevent you from fixing the root problem. The quickfix window uses several colours that are separate from any other syntax colouring (`QuickFixLine`, `qfLine`, `qfError` etc.) so you should be able to resolve any such visibility issues by using these rather than changing `Search` as you suggest.

If you are still experiencing this issue (I realise your question is almost 4 years old now) then if you could add a few more details about exactly what the problem is in the quickfix, I'm sure we could help you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto commands and put them in `~/.vimrc`.

```
au QuickFixCmdPre * hi Search ctermbg=white
```

This command will set `ctermbg` color as White before entering quickfix.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm using syntastic, maybe that matters?

Comment: Can you give `:verbose hi Search` in command line? So that we can check whether the color is changed by syntactic or any other plugin?

Comment: It says `Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/morning.vim`; the command doesn't seem to be called at all.

Comment: Can you put the auto command line in a plugin inside `after` directory? This plugin may be created like /home/username/.vim/after/plugin/pluginname.vim if you don't have this yet. That might work.

Comment: I tried, but the result is the same, unfortunately.

Comment: It seems to work in my vim. Probably, you need to debug your plugins or create a issue in plugin's issue tracker (might be in github)

Comment: Okay, I will check what plugins are causing this later. Just to be sure, you are using syntastic?

Comment: Not using the plugin